# Leave Request Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mern, hybrid-mobile-app

I built Request Management Page. We have two fields Start Date and End Date, but I faced Error Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function
(for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file
it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default
and named imports.

```
`<pre><code>
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  Button,
  CalendarPicker,
} from "react-native";

const Leave_Request = () => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState("");
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState("");

  const onStartDateChange = (date) => {
    setStartDate(date);`your text`
  };

  const onEndDateChange = (date) => {
    setEndDate(date);
  };

  const onSubmit = () => {
    alert(`Apply leave for ${startDate} - ${endDate}`);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.header}>Leave Request Form</Text>
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Start Date"
        style={styles.input}
        onChange={onStartDateChange}
      />
      <CalendarPicker
        value={startDate}
        onChange={onStartDateChange}
        style={styles.calendar}
      />
      <TextInput
        placeholder="End Date"
        style={styles.input}
        onChange={onEndDateChange}
      />
      <CalendarPicker
        value={endDate}
        onChange={onEndDateChange}
        style={styles.calendar}
      />
      <Button
        title="Submit"
        onPress={onSubmit}
        style={styles.button}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 10,
  },
  header: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  input: {
    width: 200,
    height: 40,
    borderColor: "gray",
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  calendar: {
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    borderColor: "gray",
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: "blue",
    color: "white",
    width: 100,
    height: 40,
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
});
</code></pre>

export default Leave_Request;


* Error: Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function 
(for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file 
it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default 
and named imports.

-Check the render method of `Leave_Request`.

-I tried several times but received the same error. My default Leave_Request component export is correct.`
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).